# Database design / relationships

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I just want to check with you guys what the best way to setup my databases is, as I'm fairly new to setting up relationships correctly.

I plan to have the following setup:

**Database:** *MyCompany*
**Table:** *DocumentClassification*

```
id | discipline | type1 | type2
---|------------|-------|------
1  | A          |01     |00
2  | A          |01     |01
3  | B          |01     |00
```

**Database:** *Job1*
**Table:** *Documents*

```
id | title | doc_number | type_id
---|-------|------------|--------
1  | Doc1  |00001       |3
2  | Doc2  |00002       |1
3  | Doc3  |00003       |3
```

**Database:** *Job2*
**Table:** *Documents*

```
id | title | doc_number | type_id
---|-------|------------|--------
1  | Doc1  |00001       |2
2  | Doc2  |00002       |3
3  | Doc3  |00003       |1
```

Please note that these are separate databases, but the "type_id" column will look at the "id" column in the "DocumentClassification" table (in another database) to determine its document type.

I had opted for separate tables as we can have hundreds of jobs with tens of thousands of document in.

I'm really just wanting to check this is the correct way to approach this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having separate table or not having separate tables both options are fine as long as they complete your requirement.

If you are having separate tables then definitely you need to have information and knowledge about JOINS.

I think this ERD is completely fine.

Comment: Alex, thank you for your response. You would never include "discipline, type1 & type2" as columns in the "Documents" tables? You would always use an id reference as to not duplicate information correct?

Comment: Correct. But that would make ERD expand thus making it more complicated. I would suggest to make new table for Types if and only if types are > 4 or 5. In your ERD there are only two values 00 and 01 I wouldn't suggest new table for it. :) Don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: Alex, thank you. We currently have 555 different document types. With this in mind, would you keep it as a separate Database and Table? Also I don't currently have any triggers set up to force the foreign key across databases (I've never done it before) is that an issue? And sorry just another query, do you think because of the amount of jobs and documents having a separate database for each job is the best way to go? Thank you very much.

Comment: 555 different types deserve a new table.